# I want my button to have a fixed-cover background different than the background of the page

Tags: html, css

I have the following webpage: http://jsfiddle.net/Leytgm3L/16/

and as you can see, I have the CSS code describing button:

```
.learn-btn, .download-btn {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 18px 46px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Thanks to this - it's transparent. I want it to have the same background as the div above:

```
#black{
    background: url('http://www.geeknaut.com/images/windows-wallpapers/Cool-Windows-7-Wallpapers.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;  
    background-size: cover;
}
```

and not the background of my webpage:

```
.hero4{
background:url('http://i.imgur.com/D2ATnw8.jpg') no-repeat center center;
}
```

How can I make it, so the button not only has the background of the div above, but also this background is fixed and covered?

Comment: Is it just me or is this question very difficult to understand?

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Leytgm3L/17/

Comment: yes, exactly like this, I didn't expect that to be so easy! Please post it as an answer (not the comment), so I can accept it as the correct one! :)

Comment: easy fixes are the best fixes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the image to the back ground of your button http://jsfiddle.net/Leytgm3L/17/ like this:

```
#black{
    background: url('http://www.geeknaut.com/images/windows-wallpapers/Cool-Windows-7-Wallpapers.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;  
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Oh and I just copy pasted you current image stuff right into the button background, you can get away with a lot less. I just updated it to get you on the right track.

Comment: Hi @Adam, what do you mean by getting away with a lot less? For me the only option is to set up a background image like you did, but maybe there's more efficient way?